# Is there any way to change a Kotlin when statement so that it includes an enum more efficiently?

Tags: kotlin

Is there any way to change a Kotlin when statement so that it includes an enum more efficiently?

For example:

```
val objectType = when (directoryType) {
    UnixFileType.D -> "d"
    UnixFileType.HYPHEN_MINUS -> "-"
    UnixFileType.L -> "l"
}
```

To:

```
val objectType = when (directoryType.UnixFileType) {
   D -> "d"
   HYPHEN_MINUS -> "-"
   L -> "l"
}
```

I have done some digging and haven't found a working solution. Does anybody know if I'm just messing something up or if it's a work in progress or just something they don't be adding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, you just need to import the specific enum values directly:

```
import com.example.UnixFileType.D
import com.example.UnixFileType.HYPHEN_MINUS
import com.example.UnixFileType.L

val objectType = when (directoryType) {
    D -> "d"
    HYPHEN_MINUS -> "-"
    L -> "l"
}
```

Or with a star import:

```
import com.example.UnixFileType.*

val objectType = when (directoryType) {
    D -> "d"
    HYPHEN_MINUS -> "-"
    L -> "l"
}
```

---

Hint: You can convert the more verbose version by placing your cursor on one of the `UnixFileType`'s and choosing the *Import members from `com.example.UnixFileType`* intention action.